# Multiplying with a string in java

Tags: java

I have a string and want to multiply that string by .174.

I have `String strNumber = numberText.getText();`. How to  I proceed from here?

Comment: A `String` is not a `Number`.

Comment: No, you have a `String` that you want to convert into a number, which you then want to multiply. The JavaDocs for `String` will help you do this.

Comment: Any chance you could choose a correct answer?

Answer (score 6):

Convert the string to whatever number datatype is appropriate (`long` if a big number, `float`/`double` for decimals etc.) using `Long.parseLong(String)` or `Integer.parseInteger(String)` etc. Then you can simply multiply the two numbers.
Example:

```
String string1 = ".5";//Double in a string
String string2 = "6"; //Integer in a string
double multiplied = Double.parseDouble(string1) * Integer.parseInt(string2) * 3; //.5 * 6 * 3 = 9.0; number form (not string)
```

Comment: +1 But, they probably want double not int since they are multiplying by .174.

Comment: Ahh, did not see the decimal point there, I'll modify my example just to help a little :) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Before you can do anything with the number, you have to convert the value to an floating-point value.  You can use the following approach:

```
double num = Double.parseDouble(numberText.getText())
```

Then you can perform your multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

```
String strNumber = numberText.getText();;
    if (strNumber.contains(".")) {
        System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(strNumber) * 174);
    } else {
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(strNumber) * 174);
    }
```